# Display/return last 12 and 24 months with year from current month and year using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime

I want to make one function that will take input current month and current year and will give the output of last 12 and 24 months with years,

for example, lets suppose the function is f,

```
 f(4,2019) # 4 is the current month and 2019 is the current year
```

This function will return two two outputs

```
 first output:
 [3,2,1,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4]  # last 12 months from current month i.e. 4

 [2019,2019,2019,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018] 
  # the years of corresponding months

second output:
[3,2,1,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4] # last 24 months

[2019,2019,2019,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,
2018,2018,2018,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017]  
# years of above months
```

How to do it in most effective way in python ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function:

```
import datetime

import dateutil.relativedelta

def get_prev_month_date(year, month, period):

    years, months = ([] for j in range(2))
    for i in range(1, period+ 1):
        date = datetime.date(year, month, 3)
        months.append((date - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=i)).month)
        years.append((date - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=i)).year)
    return years, months
```

Code:

```
years_list, months_list = get_prev_month_date(2019, 4, 12)
```

Results:

```
[2019, 2019, 2019, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018]
[3, 2, 1, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Pandas' library to set the today's date, and your target prior months.

```
import pandas as pd

today = pd.to_datetime('today').strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
last = (pd.to_datetime(today) - pd.DateOffset(years=1)).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

listofmonths = pd.date_range(start=last, end=today, freq='MS')
```

If you want to get 24 months, set `years` to 2.

Answer (score 1):

The most effective way is to avoid doing the date arithmetic yourself and use `dateutil` to do it for you.

```
>>> from dateutil import parser, relativedelta
>>> d = parser.parse('2019-04-01')
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 1, 0, 0)
>>> previous = [d - relativedelta.relativedelta(months=m) for m in range(1,13)]
>>> previous
[datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 1, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 1, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 1, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 1, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 1, 0, 0)]
```

To get 24 months rather than 12, substitute `25` for `13` in the list comprehension.

You will probably find it more convenient to get `datetime`s back from your function rather than integers. It's easy to extract date and month from a `datetime`, formatting is *much* more convenient, and you will probably have to turn them back into `datetime`s at some point anyway.

Comment: thanks, please upvote this question, otherwise I will be banned from asking questions

Answer (score 1):

Even if stackoverflow isn't actually a code-writing service... this should do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def f(month, year):
  m=range(12, 0, -1)*3
  y=[year]*12+[year-1]*12
  return m[13-month:(13-month+12)], y[13-month:(13-month+12)]


print f(4, 2019)
```

Output is:

```
([3, 2, 1, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4], [2019, 2019, 2019, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018])
```

You can derive the version for two years from it yourself.

Comment: I am getting following error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'range' and 'int'

Comment: for python3 use `m=list(range(12, 0, -1))*3` instead.

Comment: please upvote this question, otherwise I will be banned from asking questions